# Test that function doesn't go into an infinite loop

Tags: python, testing

I have a function which sometimes goes into the infinite loop.
I want to write an integration test to check that that doesn't happen; i.e. the functions is too big/complex to modify, so testing has to be external.
Basically, I know that it should always finish within `x` amount of time, if it takes more than `x`, it is in an infinite loop.

I'm using `pytest` as my testing framework. Is there a simple way to set a timer for functions execution?

I roughly understand how I can do it with threads/processes, but I was wondering if there is an existing approach.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Timeout on a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call)

Comment: That seems to do what I want, if you post it as an answer I will accept it.